# Cocoa: Finding the missing reference for deallocating

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, instruments, dealloc, retaincount

I'm almost done with and app and I'm using instruments to analyse it. I'm having a problem with ARC deallocating something, but I don't know what. I run instruments using the allocations tool ,what I'm doing is starting the app at the main view, then I mark a heap, I interact with the app a little and return to the original main view and mark another heap.

I do this several times and as I understand it, there should not be any significant heap growth because I am returning to the exact same place, everything I did in between should have been deallocated, providing no heap growth. However I have significant growth so I dive into the heaps and I find that almost everything on it has a retain count of 1, which leads me to believe that one object or view, etc is not being deallocated because of a mistake I've made and that object is what's holding references to everything else.

What I'm trying to find out is which object is not being deallocated. Instruments is very vague and only offers obscure pointers that do not allow me to trace back the problem.

Please let me know if there is a way for me to trace what is holding a reference that may be keeping the retain count at 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My 1st thought are 2 things:
1) You may have a retain cycle: As an example, one object has to a delegate a strong reference. And the delegate has also a strong reference (instead of a weak reference) to the 1st object back. Since both of them "hold" the other one, none of them can be released.
2) You may have a multi-threaded app, one of the threads does not have an autorelease pool assigned (i.e. does not have an `@autoreleasepool` block), and is creating autorelease objects. This may happen even in a simple getter method that returns an autorelease object. If so, the autorelease object is "put" into an non-existing autorelease pool (which does not give you an error message, since you can send any message to `nil`), and it is never released.
Maybe one of these cases applies to your problem.

Comment: I think the second option you said might be happening. Although I haven't explicitly created any additional threads, sometimes when an error pops up as lldb I am taken to a view that shows several simultaneous threads, I never thought much of it, I would think that they're auto created for more fundamental level stuff. Still if this might be it, how would I make an autorelease pool for a thread I didn't create?

Comment: That's easy: Simply enclose the code of the thread in an autorelease block @autoreleasepool {...your code...}, see <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html>

Comment: I don't know at what part in my code the new thread is created, like I said, I don't call any NSThread method explicitly, I only believe I have multiple threads because when I get an lldb error several threads are shown. How can I tell where in my code the autorelease block would go? I tried several from what the documentation said but none seems to have changed anything. That's why I'd like to narrow down to what specific object is not being dealloced.

Comment: There are many ways to create threads. The most common ones are calls to performSelectorInBackground:, performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, and to put something into a dispatch queue of the Grand Central Dispatch system. If you use some of them, in most cases it is necessary to enclose your code in the selector by an @autoreleasepool block.

Comment: I'm trying to find a definitive list of all the methods that create separate threads to see if I'm using any of them. Can't seem to find anything like that and I don't see anything obvious in my code.

Comment: In most cases, threads are created by messages like "performSelector" (in background, after delay, etc.), by NSOperation objects and "blocks" (like the completion block of an animation or one that you put into an operation or dispatch queue). For details, please lookup the docs <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html>.